# Using side_effect for class property doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) attribute of [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) but it only seems to work if I am patching functions. However, I would like to patch properties. Here's a minimal code example:

```
# in calendar.py
class Weeks():
    a = property(lambda self: 0)
    b = property(lambda self: 0)
    c = property(lambda self: 0)

@patch('calendar.Weeks')
def test_something_else(weeks_mock):

    weeks_mock.return_value.a.side_effect = [0, 10, 20, 30]
    weeks_mock.return_value.b = 40
    weeks_mock.return_value.c = 50
    # some more code...
```

I've also unsuccessfully tried using [`PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) like this:

```
@patch('calendar.Weeks')
def test_something_else(weeks_mock):

    type(weeks_mock).a = PropertyMock(side_effect=[0, 10, 20, 30])
    weeks_mock.return_value.b = 40
    weeks_mock.return_value.c = 50
    # some more code...
```

I would highly appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1):

> Use `__get__` to mock and test the class attribute

**get**
Description

Called to get the attribute of the owner class (class attribute access) or of an instance of that class (instance attribute access).

```
with mock.patch.object(Weeks, 'a') as mock_a:
    mock_a.__get__ = mock.Mock(return_value='mocked_cls_attr')
    self.assertEqual(Weeks.a, 'mocked_cls_attr')
```

Not sure why you got the error, Here is a working test to help you figure out the eror.

```
import unittest
import mock


class Weeks():
    a = property(lambda self: 0)
    b = property(lambda self: 0)
    c = property(lambda self: 0)


class TestWeeks(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch.object(Weeks, 'a')
    @mock.patch.object(Weeks, 'b')
    @mock.patch.object(Weeks, 'c')
    def test_something_else(self, mockc, mockb, mocka):
        # the attr a now mocka is becoming a function using side_effect
        mocka.side_effect = [0, 10, 20, 30]
        mockb.__get__ = mock.Mock(return_value=40)
        mockc.__get__ = mock.Mock(return_value=50)

        # mocka() not mocka as it is a function now
        self.assertEqual(mocka(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(mocka(), 10)
        week = Weeks()
        self.assertEqual(week.b, 40)
        self.assertEqual(week.c, 50)
        # week.a with using function will trigger a failure
        # AssertionError: <MagicMock name='a' id='139943677051600'> != 20
        self.assertEqual(week.a(), 20)

    def test_property(self):
        # no need to mock a property object, just replace it
        week = Weeks()
        week.a = property(lambda self: 1)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(week.a, property))
        self.assertEqual(week.a.fget(0), 1)
```

Run test:

```
nosetests -v python2_unittests/tests/test_cls_attr.py
```

Results:

```
test_something_else (python2_unittests.tests.test_cls_attr.TestWeeks) ... ok
```

Comment: I've tried it out in various ways but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I keep getting variations of the same error: AssertionError: <MagicMock name='a' id='4375261816'> != 'mocked_cls_attr. It seems like the same problem that I had before - instead of returning a value it returns a MagicMock instance...

Comment: @MarkFingerhuth, it is probably the `side_effect` force class attribute `a` to become a function, you have to call `Weeks.a()` instead of `Weeks.a`

Comment: I really appreciate your input but I can't just switch it from a property to a function since I am testing a really complex piece of code (I'm mocking the responses of Github's python API interface PyGithub). So I really need to be able to keep it as a property. Maybe there is another way without using `unittest.mock`?

Comment: @MarkFingerhuth, u r right, it is property object, no need to mock, just replace it with another property.

Answer (score 0):

[`PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) will work if you pass it as `new_callable` to a `patch` for each property:

```py
class Weeks():
    a = property(lambda self: 0)
    b = property(lambda self: 0)
    c = property(lambda self: 0)

@patch('__main__.Weeks.a', new_callable=PropertyMock)
@patch('__main__.Weeks.b', new_callable=PropertyMock)
@patch('__main__.Weeks.c', new_callable=PropertyMock)
def test_something_else(mock_c, mock_b, mock_a):

    mock_a.side_effect = [0, 10, 20, 30]
    mock_b.return_value = 40
    mock_c.return_value = 50
    # some more code...
    weeks = Weeks()
    assert weeks.a == 0
    assert weeks.a == 10
    assert weeks.b == 40
    assert weeks.c == 50
```

In fact, your example with `PropertyMock` works for `a`. I just had to adapt `b` and `c` for it to completely work:

```py
@patch('__main__.Weeks')
def test_something_else(weeks_mock):
    type(weeks_mock).a = PropertyMock(side_effect=[0, 10, 20, 30])
    type(weeks_mock).b = PropertyMock(return_value=40)
    type(weeks_mock).c = PropertyMock(return_value=50)
    # some more code...
    assert weeks_mock.a == 0
    assert weeks_mock.a == 10
    assert weeks_mock.b == 40
    assert weeks_mock.c == 50
```

And if you need more complicated logic, patch directly to a new `property`:

```py
@patch('__main__.Weeks.a', property(lambda self: 40 if self.b else 50))
def test_something_complicated():
    # some more code...
    weeks = Weeks()
    assert weeks.a == 50
```

Comment: Please include some form of explanation with your answer so the OP  and others can learn from it. Specifically, why it solves the users problem.